# vba match function case sensivity

Tags: excel, vba, match, case-sensitive

Im working with 200 files, where I have to open each of them, find specific column and enter data in this column.

The problem is that in these files sometimes I have column header like `Local Dividend` with capital letters, but sometimes I have `local dividend` with lower case letters. There are also files where one is capital and one is not eg. `Local dividend`.

The problem is that when I use `application.match("Local Dividend",range("A1:AD1"),0)` I will get a match only when the text is the same (with capital letters).

I tried `Option Compare Text` but with match it does not working.

Is there a way/code which can help avoid comparing capital/lower case letters in MATCH?

[match in cell as formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkOIm.png)
Thanks

Comment: The help page for Match states "Match does not distinguish between uppercase and lowercase letters when matching text values." so maybe your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: You could use the `Find` method instead as that has a matchcase parameter.

Comment: Hi freeflow
I have seen this also however I tried to use Match in excel sheet as a cell formula. 
I got N/A when I used "Dividend" in cell and "dividend" as a searched text (see attached image above)

Comment: @EmiliaRajchel Both formula and `Application.Match()` are case insensitive. It seems that you don't compare "Local Dividend" but "Local Payroll" in your formula.